# Creating itemsets from pandas dataframe with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-mining

I am having a dataframe whith 102377 rows, which looks like the following:

```
Queries
        term                     timestamp
        ...
        queryA                   2018-09-27 18:26:47
        queryB                   2018-09-27 18:26:52
        2547                     2018-09-27 18:26:58
        queryX                   2018-09-28 14:29:49
        queryP                   2018-09-28 14:30:00
        2157                     2018-09-28 14:30:01
        queryA                   2018-09-29 10:14:15
        queryY                   2018-09-29 10:14:19
        queryX                   2018-09-30 12:20:40
        queryP                   2018-09-30 12:22:00
        queryA                   2018-09-30 12:22:01
        queryU                   2018-09-30 12:26:08
        13324                    2018-09-30 12:30:00
        ...
```

I want to create Itemsets of terms out of the dataframe. For this I would like to proceed as follows: I start at the last term, if the term is numeric a new itemset should be created. If the term before is not numeric and the timedelta is under 10 minutes, the term belongs into the itemset. In the end it should look like this:

```
itemsets
 index    terms
 0        13324; queryU; queryA; queryP; queryX
 1        2157; queryP; queryX
 2        2547; queryB; queryA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try with [`Series.str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) and [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table):

```
df2 = df[::-1]
new_df = df2.pivot_table(index=df2['term'].str.isnumeric().cumsum(),
                         values='term', 
                         aggfunc='; '.join)
print(new_df)

                                                   term
term                                                   
1     13324; queryU; queryA; queryP; queryX; queryY;...
2                                  2157; queryP; queryX
3                                  2547; queryB; queryA
```

We can also use

```
 pd.to_numeric(df2['term'], errors='coerce').notna().cumsum()
```

Instead [`Series.str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html)

Comment: The first alternative just gives me a dataframe with one row of itemsets with 3000 items. And the second one throws this error: TypeError: pivot_table() got multiple values for argument 'values'

Comment: does `df.pivot_table(index=pd.to_numeric(df2['term'], errors='coerce').notna().cumsum(),
               values='term',
               aggfunc='; '.join)`  return that error?

Comment: No, my fault. But unfortunately it doesn´t work either. I just get a dataframe with 4870 rows with the value term (literally).